# Make JavaScript change background image every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change my background image every 5 seconds. How should I go about this?

```
window.onload = function () {

  function Timer() {
    window.setInterval("changeImage()", 5000);
  }

  function changeImage() {   
    var BackgroundImg["./Img/Bg1.jpg",
                      "./Img/Bg2.jpg",
                      "./Img/Bg3.jpg",
                      "./Img/Bg4.jpg"];
    var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
    var bgImg = document.body.style.backgroundImage();
    bgImg.url = BackgroundImg[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669608/javascript-foreach-loop-through-an-array-of-hex-values-using-settimeout-to-loop

Comment: @Kyle McCarthy: i suggest instead getting random values. make a array with totalimage length. shuffle it. and proceed from index 0. if you are reaching final index. then again shuffle and proceed. dueto this you can avoid same image Repetition

Comment: What do you see when you add breakpoints and step through the code?

Answer (score 3):

You can make few changes

1.Not sure from where you are calling Timer function (better if
    have camelCase)

```
function Timer() {
    window.setInterval("changeImage()", 5000);
  }
```

Instead you can directly use

```
setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
```

`changeImage` is a callback

2.Could not make out what is this line mean

```
var bgImg = document.body.style.backgroundImage();
```

Unsure if can attach a function to style property.

Anyway this below  snippet can be useful

```
window.onload = function () {
     // Array of Images
      var backgroundImg=["https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRyB57zuc4bms-hDtWMa-4BZvscIlJDm4r7a9WLaO4SAxUvKM-DDA",
                        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQBinSpWOvAtkxjmkf709O3rjH2ObRbWAEn9s0JcWaeL6LMtCbOrQ",
                        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKY4J2qIFqkuDnABMzeypywbMSZL1cleS8vpySz0KD02wOYORU1g",
                        "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQkdQT0zN0xDVP-VuvwojSbS5dOstX14eZvJCOWNPxKJ5dWTIc"
                        ]

        setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
       function changeImage() {   
        var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));

        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+backgroundImg[i]+"')";

      }
    }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/eu0ksuy9/)

Comment: is there a way to make the array of images dynamic, so if I upload more images to a folder it just uses all the images in the folder  ?

Answer (score 2):

you are accessing style incorrectly

```
window.onload = function () {

    function changeImage() {   
        var BackgroundImg=["./Img/Bg1.jpg",
            "./Img/Bg2.jpg",
            "./Img/Bg3.jpg",
            "./Img/Bg4.jpg"
        ];
        var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4));
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + BackgroundImg[i] + '")';
    }
    window.setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
}
```

Also, if possible (usually is) don't pass a string to `window.setInterval` - use as above

Comment: also the function `timer()` is never called.

Comment: didn't notice that in the original :D - doesn't need to be a function, just window.setInterval will do :p

Comment: Shouldn't it be 4, not 3?

Comment: @torazaburo - aaaaarghhh yes - not my logic problem though - I can't be expected to debug every single line of the original question to make sure it makes sense !! :p (kidding)

Comment: I may be incorrect, but I think your'e missing '=' in 'var BackgroundImg["./Img/Bg1.jpg",
            "./Img/Bg2.jpg",
            "./Img/Bg3.jpg",
            "./Img/Bg4.jpg"
        ];'

Comment: I may be incorrect, but I think your'e missing `=` in `var BackgroundImg["./Img/Bg1.jpg",
            "./Img/Bg2.jpg",
            "./Img/Bg3.jpg",
            "./Img/Bg4.jpg"
        ];`

Comment: @AndrewE - yes ... 3 years and you're the only one to spot my deliberate mistake of not fixing that part of the code :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to your question. Hope it helps!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>change picture</title>
  <script type = "text/javascript">
      function displayNextImage() {
          x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
          document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
      }
      function changeImage() {
          setInterval(displayNextImage, 5000);
      }

      var images = [], x = -1;
      images[0] = "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg";
      images[1] = "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/background-gmail-google-images_FG2XwaO.jpg";
      images[2] = "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/beautiful-sunset-images-196063.jpg";
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload = "changeImage()">
   <img id="img" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/beautiful-sunset-images-196063.jpg"/>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You can replace the URL I used with your pictures.

Comment: Hello Henry and there's a way to change it but with some kind of animation? or transition? @HenryDev